# Gnuplot: vertical space between series titles

Tags: gnuplot, space, legend

How to change the vertical space between series titles. Is it possible to separate the series titles into two groups and have a gap between them, like this one:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert some kind of 'dummy' plot where you want to have the white space:

```
set xrange [0:4]
set key left
plot x, \
     2*x t '2x', \
     NaN title ' ' lt -3,\
     3*x t '3x',\
     4*x t '4x'
```

The special linetype `-3` doesn't draw any line at all, using `linewidth 0` wouldn't work for all terminals (e.g. postscript). And the title must contain one space character, otherwise the key entry would be dismissed.

[image]

Comment: I know you now. :) you are an expert on gnuplot.