# How to place keys (legends) horizontally in groups

Tags: key, gnuplot

How to place keys (legends) of data series horizontally in groups in gnuplot?

Here is an example I worked out using ms paint:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the maximum number of rows in the key with

```
set key left maxrows 4
```

Then you must distribute some empty lines in your key as I showed in my answer to [Gnuplot: vertical space between series titles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23022770/gnuplot-vertical-space-between-series-titles). In your case it is very convenient to define a macro for the empty line:

```
set xrange [0:4]
set key left maxrows 4

set macros
dummy="NaN title ' ' lt -3"

plot x, 2*x, @dummy, @dummy,\
     3*x, 4*x, @dummy, @dummy,\
     5*x, 6*x, @dummy, @dummy,\
     7*x, 8*x, 9*x, 10*x
```

[image]